# ASCII character rectangular box

Tags: c++, ascii

I am kind of new to c++. so I've been asked to do a rectangular box using ASCII code using function, the characters must be 202,203, 204,216,217,221, I've tried searching and editing so I came up with this code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int rectangular (int i)
{

cout << char(203);
for(int i=0; i<=40;i++);
cout << char(203);
cout << char(203)<<endl;
cout<< char (221);
for(int i=0;i<1;i++)cout<<' ';
cout<<char (221);
cout<<endl<<char (204);
for(int i=0; i<10;i++);
cout<<char (216);
cout<<char (217);

 return 0;
}

int main() 

{
    int n,i;
    rectangular(n); 
}
```

Managed to be executed but the result is horrific, too small 0.0

I am terribly sorry for asking such question but most of codes I found online use char (201) and now I have to make the code just as good as expected output by using these unique characters.

Is there any way to extend the horizontal line atleast?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Technically characters whose values are above 127 are not [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: As for your problem, your loops doesn't print anything, maybe that's your problem? (Hint: The semicolon after the loop means that nothing will be done except the actual looping.)

Comment: Okay, noted, I got the concept now :), okay turns out the looping was to extend horizontally, would you please tell me how to do vertically?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Not just technically.  The aren't ASCII, and their meaning (if any) depends on the encoding being used.

Answer (score 2):

Take the semi colons off your loops

```
for(int i=0; i<=40;i++);
```

should be

```
for(int i=0; i<=40;i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loops execute a statement, that statement is, in your case, an empty statement terminated by the semicolon after the loop.

You loop looks like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<=40;i++);
```

If I reformat it a little, the loop is like this

```
for(int i=0; i<=40;i++)
    ; // <- empty statement
```

So the loop iterates 41 times, doing nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get the basic concept but it only will loop horizontally, what if I also want to loop vertically so it'll be a big rectangular box?